# Is there an unlimited API for finding Latitudes and Longitudes given an address?

Tags: php, google-api

I am using an API for find Latitudes and Longitudes from address dynamically. The address comes from a database. Now I am using Google's API for this but there is a limit of 15,000 records per day. I have 50,000 records in my database and this may increase in the future.

So I want an API which can convert as many records (address to Latitudes and Longitudes) as possible. I.e., there should be no limit of number of records. If you know of any API for this please share it with me.

I cannot use Yahoo's API for this. Is there an unlimited Google API for this?

Comment: So...15,000 records per day should take you 4 days.  Am I missing something?  Are you worried you will eventually need to process more than 15,000 per day?  Surely once you make it through your backlog, 15,000 should be plenty, no?

Answer (score 1):

Try purchasing a copy of IP2Location, or caching your records in case duplicates are being made.